# swift 5 - String to Date conversion results in nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, swift5

Has something changed in Swift 5.x? Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

[image]

```
    extension String {
      var dateValue: Date? {
        let dateAsString = "13:15"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString) //date is being nil here
        let Date24 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
        print("24 hour formatted Date:",Date24)
        return date
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is your phone set up in 12h format? Moght need en_us_posix before.

Comment: your screenshot and given code aren't same. Which code you are using?

Comment: Your code and your screenshot are not the same. The function`setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` is for converting dates to strings not the other way around.

Comment: Updated the question with correct picture and details @Fogmeister and Ankur Lahiry

Comment: @rakappdev you need to set your DateFormatter locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting the other properties when parsing a fixed date format. You should set your date formatter calendar as well and if possible its defaultDate.

Answer (score 6):

Change your code to :

```
let dateAsString = "13:15"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+00:00")//Add this
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)
print(date!)
```

My result is :

```
2000-01-01 13:15:00 +0000
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I'm still seeing it as nil. Does any of this have to do with the fact that all of this is happening inside an extension?

Comment: My result is not nil. Are your sure your code same as mine?

Comment: Apparently this looks like a bug in Xcode/Swift 5.x as it's not showing nil if I try to print the date object. It is however showing nil when trying to debug by hovering over the variable as shown in the attached picture in Question.